# convert from hostnames to ip address and vice versa

Tags: sockets, networking, dns, ip-address

What if two or more different domains which are not alias(using Cname) are hosted on the same server?

There are two perspectives :

1. How a server with same IP address resolves two different host names ?
2. As a user/client  can I know how server resolves the hostname and  assign some unique ID to different domain names using which they can be distinctly identified ?